# Ajax - problem with response inside a div

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to show the value of ajax response inside a div.Ajax. Problem arise when I get the response. Response is showing in the div only for split second and hides automatically. I tried changing id to class but the error persist still. The alert displays properly when tested. What do I miss? I have the following code in my view file.

**The div:**

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Ajax:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#submit').click(function() {

 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  cache: false,
  url:'save.php',
  data: $("#action").serialize(),
  dataType: "html",

 success: function(response) {

if(response == 'success')
{
    alert('success');
}
if(response == 'empty')
{
    alert('empty');

}
if(response == 'bad')
{
     $("#result").html(response);

}
}

 });
});
});
```

**save.php:**

```
<?php
$co= 'aaa';

if(!empty($_POST['tosave']))
{

    if($_POST['tosave'] == $co)
{
    $foo = fopen("plik.txt","a+");

            flock($foo, 2);
            fwrite($foo,$_POST['tosave']."\r\n");
            flock($foo ,3);
            fclose($foo);
echo "success";
exit();
} else {

    echo 'bad';
    exit;
}

} else {

echo "empty";
exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: I think all you need is put response in nested if else may be that will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you don't prevent the default behavior on the submit button which is to send the form's data to the specified link, maybe in your case the link is on the same page than your PHP leading to only see the message in the div for a split second before the page reloads itself.

So to prevent this default behavior, you have to catch the event and use the [preventDefault() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) like so :

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) { //we pass the event as an attribute
event.preventDefault(); //we prevent its default behavior so we can do our own stuff below
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  cache: false,
  url:'save.php',
  data: $("#action").serialize(),
  dataType: "html",

 success: function(response) {

    if(response == 'success')
    {
       alert('success');
    }
    if(response == 'empty')
    {
       alert('empty');

    }
    if(response == 'bad')
    {
        $("#result").html(response);

    }   
}

  });
 });
 });
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); fixed problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Ok ,no probs. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a mistake in your **Ajax call** code you have write your `submit.click()` submit function under `document.ready()`.remove `document.ready()` because `submit.click()`will run when you submit the form. Second thing is you should add 
`event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behabiour of your submit form otherwise it will display for short time and then it will disappeared.See my code below it is working.

**AJAX WITH HTML FORM:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="action">
        <input type="text" name="tosave" value="bbb">
        <button type="submit">clickme</button>>
    </form>

    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#action").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();//TO PREVENT THE DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR OF FORM
     $.ajax
     ({
      type:'post',
      cache: false,
      url:'https:save.php',
      data: $("#action").serialize(),
      dataType: "html",

     success: function(response) {

    if(response == 'success')
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    if(response == 'empty')
    {
        alert('empty');

    }
    if(response == 'bad')
    {
         $("#result").html(response);

    }
    }

     });
    });



    </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$co = 'aaa';

if (!empty($_POST['tosave'])) {

    if ($_POST['tosave'] == $co) {
        $foo = fopen("plik.txt", "a+");

        flock($foo, 2);
        fwrite($foo, $_POST['tosave'] . "\r\n");
        flock($foo, 3);
        fclose($foo);
        echo "success";
        exit();
    } else {

        echo 'bad';
        exit;
    }

} else {

    echo "empty";
    exit;

}
?>
**OUTPUT DISPLAY IN DIV: bad**
```